# Facebook "Like" button error

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

I added a standard Like button to my website.  The code is

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="mccabece.com"; data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

When I click the "Like" button it says I like it, but then gives a red "error" beside it. The error says - The page failed to provide a valid list of administrators. It needs to specify the administrators using either a "fb:app_id" meta tag, or using a "fb:admins" meta tag to specify a comma-delimited list of Facebook users. - When I refresh the website, it doesn't show that I've "Liked" it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what caused that exact error you mentioned...but I found some possible issues:

First, why do you have a ; character in there?

Secondly, the url you are using is not valid (this is most likely the cause of the error): use http://mccabece.com instead.

And lastly, I notice you have set data-send="true"...here's what the facebook api says "send - specifies whether to include a Send button with the Like button. This only works with the XFBML version." Make sure you set everything correctly to use that.

Edit:

About the app id, check out this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

You can see the code they give uses the app id.

You can create a new app here, from your facebook account: https://developers.facebook.com/apps and use the id from there.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for taking the time to look at my problem. I'm not sure where the ; came from. It wasn't actually in my code. I didn't write the code. I got it from Facebooks website. I changed the url and tried it with the data-send as "false" also and I still get this error. Here is the other code I added, if that's any help. I am also wondering if I need to link this to my Facebook page somehow. Could that be why I'm getting an administrator error?

Comment: Other sript: <div id="fb-root"></div> <script>(function(d, s, id) { var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>           Sorry, but I can't get the script to paste as it should.

Comment: I did generate the scripts and insert them. I also generated one for open graph tags. It says to insert in the <HEAD>. I'm not sure where or if it goes in one script or the other or what.  <meta property="og:title" content="McCabe Construction and Electric LLC" />
<meta property="og:type" content="company" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://mccabece.com" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.mccabece.com/images/19280146_e5zv.jpg" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="McCabe Construction and Electric LLC" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="100002290832154" />

Comment: from the error it seems there is something wrong with these last set of tags. 1. did you try without them? does it work like this? 2. is the content for the property fb:admins your facebook id? check if that is correct..

Comment: I have tried without them.  I'm not sure I even inserted them correctly.  I'm using Godaddy as a host and using website tonight as the website editor.  I'm not sure if the admins id is my id, but that's the script that was generated and I was logged into my facebook account.

Comment: try generating another set of codes just to make sure everything is right and try with only the other 2 sets of codes.

Answer (score 0):

To get through this i had to log out of my facebook account - then went to the https://developers.facebook.com/apps page and generated the "like button" code - embedded it on my site. After all this i then clicked on the like button and i was prompted to login to my facebook account by a window pop-up - which i did. I was then after presented with a like button box amongst other few things - i then clicked on the like button again and the window disappeared. Back on my site the like button was now urging me to "confirm" which i did.From here it went back to normal with no "error" like the former times.