# Like button - error 500 from Facebook on new domain

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I encountered a strange behavior from the Facebook like button on a new site I'm building : the like button won't work on the website URL, but will work for other URL.

Webiste is @ http://bit.ly/RbMDcZ .

To be more specific, whatever version (HTML5 / XFBML / iFrame ) of the button I use, the same issue occurs : the like button don't send the comment on the wall, the like isn't even showed on Facebook and a javascript error is risen :

```
POST https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like/comment 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

App ID and other stuff seems to be all good, regarding the fact that using other link will cause no issue to link / recommand.

The subdomain used for this website is newly created, I'm wondering if it could be DNS-related, so propagation issue, and Facebook wouln't allow to link an URL it couldn't reach ?

I found some questiosn related like [Facebook like servererror 500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11932700/facebook-like-server-error-500) or [Facebook “Like” button error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9045825/facebook-like-button-error), but none really helped me go throught this. I'm not really used to play with the Facebook API, and I may have done something wrong, but I can't find out.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a cross domain issue. That type of issue needs to be resolved with the jsonp version of the like button. You might find is useful to get a web-debugging proxy like Charle which you can use to see the nature of the request the like button is making and the rendered response. Then you can ask more specific questions about the type of error that is being thrown. Good luck.

Comment: I'm really doubtful that it could be a cross-domain related issue, regarding the fact that the like system is fully functionnal of other url, including the main (www.) domain the website is hosted on. And there isn't any cross-domain restriction in place, I even added an `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` in .htaccess to extend liberty on that matter.

But I'll look into it anyway, thanks.

Comment: Also a debugger proxy like Charles will give you better errors to put up on Stack overflow :P